# express is not defined in express

Tags: node.js, express

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('hello world');
});
app.listen(3000);
```

I am getting the following error.

```
> D:\nodejs\mynode\index.js:2  
> var app=express();
    ^
ReferenceError: express is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\nodejs\mynode\index.js:2:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
```

Comment: have you run `npm install express` before trying to load the module?

Comment: yes i installed but its not working

Comment: use `sudo npm install -g express` command on your terminal to install the express module.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

should enter your code directory and use "npm install" in your shell!

Comment: have you successfully installed all the node_modules? what's your system? windows? Linux? or MacOS? when you install the dependences, you may find what's wrong during the installation! waring? or error?!

Answer (score 15):

For using express you need to follow these steps:

1) Basic setup with express

Maybe you have to use `sudo`

`npm install -g express`

This command will install express globally.
Also you can now use express on the command line.

You can now use express to setup a basic environment using this command.

`express [options] [dir]`

Options:

```
-h, --help          output usage information
-V, --version       output the version number
-s, --sessions      add session support
-e, --ejs           add ejs engine support (defaults to jade)
-J, --jshtml        add jshtml engine support (defaults to jade)
-H, --hogan         add hogan.js engine support
-c, --css <engine>  add stylesheet <engine> support (less|stylus) (defaults to plain css)
-f, --force         force on non-empty directory
```

2) Basic setup with the package.json

Create two files:

`package.json`

`index.js`

The `package.json` includes lots of project informations.

This is a example package.json:

```
{
    "name": "MyProject",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "~3.4.4"
    }
}
```

If you join now your project folder and run
`npm install`

npm will look up the `"dependencies"` and install them.

Now open you index.js and write following.

```
var express = require('express'); // Get the module
var app = express(); // Create express by calling the prototype in var express
```

Comment: Two problems with this answer:  1) You should not have to sudo to install node modules.  2) -g should only be used for global feature install and not to install express into a single local directory.

Answer (score 1):

If you successfully installed EXPRESS but then also you get
***ReferenceError: express is not defined.***

Then,

just put name of variable in first line and function name in second line same like this:-

```
var express = require('express');  
var app = express();
```

Not Like This:-

```
var exp = require('express');  
var app = express();
```

Answer (score 1):

Run this command to verify if express is properly installed in the project directory:

`npm list`

This command will also show all the packages which have been installed in your project directory.

Answer (score 0):

use this command in your terminal npm install express

make sure install inside your project folder

Answer (score 0):

check the file permissions also please. Also may be your user login do not have the permission to make changes in the system. You may have to use sudo before the command to do so if you are on ubuntu or not a root user.

Answer (score 0):

Just close your terminal and start it by right-clicking on it and selecting "Run as administrator" and then follow to the directory in which you want to create your server
and run
npm install express
done!